# How to construct the following JSONAPI url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, json-api

Im following http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level

I notice the following end-point (route):

```
/articles/1/relationships/author
```

In Rails, how would this route be contstructed in `routes.rb`?

```
resources :articles do
  # What goes here?
  # Should relationship be a namespace or other?
  # I guess author can be defined as a collection, or just a simple get
end
```

`relationships` doesn't need to have any of the 7 RESTFUL actions.

Comment: depends, do you have many other resources that would go under `/relationships` ? Where are your associated controllers (subfolders ?), what are your controller actions ?

Comment: Probably not, so I guess `namespace :relationships do; get 'author'; end;` should be fine. Which also means `get 'author'` route will point to the `author` action in the `ArticlesController`. Unless theres a way to make the `author` action exist in a `Relationships` controller instead? Which I think makes for better logical abstraction

Comment: Maybe it could be worth it to investigate if you could use [routing concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns), as this is something you could possibly reuse for many other resources, in the context of the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route should be like following code snippets:

```
resources :articles do
   resources :relationships, :only => [] do
     collection do 
       get :author
     end
   end
end
```

This is how the route file should look like. Please let me know if any update needed.

Comment: I made an edit, so the `relationships` route does not act as a resource (i.e. no index, show, etc). And explicitly specifying a controller for it so it resides inside the `articles` folder

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment clearly. Can you explain your question more precisely?

Comment: You were on the right track with your initial answer. Just a few suggestions. just specifying `resources :relationships` will expose the 7 RESTFUL actions (index, show, new, update, etc) for `relationships`. Without `controller: 'articles/relationships'`, the `author` action would exist in `relationships#author` instead of `articles/relationships#author`. Just thought I should point this out

Comment: okey, so the relationships will not need to expose any restful action right?

Comment: Yeap, let me update my initial question to make that point clear

Comment: Okey, I have done updating my answer, this should work. please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Bouncing on my idea of concerns, as you probably will have to use this in several resources (the [rails doc is quite well-written](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns))

```
concern :has_author do
  scope '/relationships' do
    resource :author
  end
end

resources :articles, concerns :has_author
```

Which is equivalent to

```
resources :articles do
  scope :'/relationships' do
    resource :author
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scope :'/relationships'` didn't work for me (At least in Rails 5).

I got it working with this:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :author, path: 'relationships/author'
end
```

This will just use the `AuthorController` and map it to `/articles/:id/relationships/author`.